# Python. "Need more than one value to unpack"

Tags: python, database, rt

```
def store_inFile(Name,Address,Area,Postcode):
    #open the file
    File2 = open("Fines.txt","rt")

    #write the name address and post code to file and save to file
    File2.write(str(Name)+"\n"+str(Address)+"\n   "+str(Area)+"\n      "+str(Postcode));File2.close()

    #set File to open the datatbase
    File =open("DATABASE.txt","rt")
    NumP_Input = str(input("Number plate of person speeding. ").upper())

    #loop each line intil the numberplate gets a match
    for line in File:
        Numberplate,Name,Address,Area,Postcode = line.split("|") #here use whatever you have splitting your database ie , . / ( |
        if NumP_Input.upper() == Numberplate:
            #output name address and number plate
            print("Fine sent to \n \n"+str(Name)+"\n"+str(Address)+"\n   "+str(Area)+"\n      "+str(Postcode));store_inFile(Name,Address,Area,Postcode)
```

I want to read from a database and if the user enters a number plate associated with the database all the information(parameters) is sent to another file.

Comment: It is unconventional in python to give variables names in CamelCase. use_underscores.

Comment: `str(input(...))` is wrong. If this is python2, use `raw_input(...)`. If it is python3, simply use `input(...)`.

Comment: after for line in file do a print of the line.  You will see the line that fails

Answer (score 1):

Check your input - the file "DATABASE.txt". There's a `line` that does not have "|" in it, so it is not "splitted to exactly five parts" as your code demands:

```
Numberplate,Name,Address,Area,Postcode = line.split("|")
```

Example:

```
>>> line = "hello, world"
>>> Numberplate,Name,Address,Area,Postcode = line.split("|")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: +1, also I'd add a check to make sure you have the correct number of elements in the split before unpacking

Comment: @elazar I would show you the database I have but I cant post the picture unfortunately

Comment: All the lines should contain exectly 4 `|` characters. Including the last line; I guess the last line in your file is empty.